# Edit default tooltips for template Checkout/onepage/Billing.phtml (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I want to edit tooltip for **"City"** field,

in

**base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml**

How can I edit the tooltip for the field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me know which content you want to show in tootip you can use this code for showing tooltip, you just have to manage it for your side:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tooltip functionality</title>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
  <script>
     $(function() {
        $("#tooltip-1").tooltip();
        $("#tooltip-2").tooltip();
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body> 
     <label for="name">Name:</label>
     <input id="tooltip-1" title="Enter You name">
     <p><a id="tooltip-2" href="#" title="Nice tooltip">
        I also have a tooltip
     </a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If your theme not have any jquery then add otherwise you dont need to that

Answer (score 0):

Here you can archive it in Magento 2 by adding this all stuff in phtml file so you 
can design it better.

In your checkout_index_index.xml.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Shipping" name="name.your.demo" after="checkout.root" template="Namespace_ModuleName::yourfile.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer> 
</body>
```

In your phtml file yourfile.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//You need to add yourDemoJs.js using requirejs-config.js
require(['jquery', 'yourDemoJs'], function ($) {

    var initYourDemo = function () {
        if (jQuery('#checkout-shipping-method-load .store-container-inner').length) {
            $('body').tour({
                steps: [{
                    title: 'Title One',
                    content: '<p>Your Content One</p>'
                }, {
                    content: '<p>Your Content Two</p>',
                    position: 'right',
                    element: '#ElementIdWhereYouWantToShow'
                }, {
                    content: '<p>Your Content Three</p>',
                    position: 'right',
                    element: '#ElementIdWhereYouWantToShow'
                }]
            });

            $('body').data('tour').start();
        } else {
            setTimeout(initMytour, 2000);
        }
    }
    initYourDemo();
});
```

Now you only need to write your js script as per your need basis you can customize as you want.